# How to install file downloaded from git clone

Tags: command-line, bash

I was trying to download hcxpcaptool in Ubuntu but I couldn't find it in the repository so I downloaded it using this command:

```
wget git clone https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools.git
```

but I am not able to install it.

I was trying to install it using this command:

```
cd hcxtools
cd hcxtools.git
```

but the output is:

```
bash: cd: hcxtools: No such file or directory
```

so how can I install this hcxpcaptool?

[image]

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools.git` is a command in its own right - don't put `wget` in front of it (that's a different protocol)

Comment: `cd ~/Desktop/hextools-master`

Comment: refer the readme file in the repository

Answer (score 2):

You want to start by reading the file labeled "README". It will tell you everything that you need to know about installing the program (or at least it should). You can ignore the hcxtools.git directory. I highly recommend getting to know git a bit more by running through some basic tutorials, but for now you can ignore that directory completely.

I see a make file in the directory you have pictured. This means that you will have to use the `make` command to build it. So from the terminal

```
sudo apt install make
cd ~/Desktop/hcxtools-master
make
```

Running `make` by itself will "target all" in the make file and build your program

Please note that I have not read the README file in that repository so I do not know if anything additional is needed.

Answer (score 1):

hey finally i've found the answer
after downloading i have to install zlib dev using this command

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-devzlib1g-dev libpcap-dev
make
make install
```

DONE.